# Comma, colon or either in my text?

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons

The author used a comma in the following text; I would have used a colon. Any thoughts?

> "She is one of only a few lawyers with the necessary skills to advise on such deals[:][,] a significant achievement for a mid-level attorney."

Comment: Please provide a reference if you can. Unreferenced quotations are not very helpful.

Comment: I'm going with a comma. A colon in this sentence and at that juncture would invite a "list" thereafter as in, "She is one of only a few lawyers with the necessary skills to advise on such deals: a sound knowledge of property development, land law and the market make her the ideal choice for your business venture".

Comment: A colon here would lead me to expect a list of those necessary skills. Absent such a list, I'd use a comma.

Comment: Either is totally correct. This is a style call. The colon has numerous uses. Here it is 'leading into a phrase or clause (one can imagine 'which is' or 'this is' here) referencing in a developmental (though it might in other cases be explanatory etc) way,  the last semantically appropriate noun phrase, or whole preceding clause'. It might be seen as too old-fashioned, while the dash (again not incorrect) might be felt to be a little informal. I stress might. An ellipsis could be used to signal a longer, dramatic pause, or a comma could be chosen for a brisker, more businesslike delivery.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Manual of Style lists one of the uses of the colon as:

> The colon points forward: from a premise to a conclusion, from a cause
>   to an effect, from an introduction to a main point; from a general
>   statement to an example. It fulfils the same function as words such as
>   *namely*, *that is*, *as*, *for example*, *for instance*, *because*, *as follows*, and *therefore*.

None of these seem to be the case here, although I can understand the temptation to assume that it is. I suspect that the author is correct.